# How to make a onChange calling only with the submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a onChange that calls every time i select an option, but i need it to call only when i click in the submit button with all fullfilled preferences. I think this may be pretty simple, but feel im missing some point... The code below is very simplified, but if solve this, it solve the remaining issues. Im using react-js, Formik and Styled Components.

I tried put the onChange in the button, but it dont fill "render"...

Is there any way to call the onSubmit inside the onChange?

The options(in json):

```
[
  { "value": "tracker_itens", "label": "Listagem de Veículos", "render": 1 },
  {
    "value": "traveled_kms",
    "label": "Listagem de KM Percorridos",
    "render": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "offline_itens",
    "label": "Listagem de Itens Offlines",
    "render": 3
  },
  {
    "value": "maintenance",
    "label": "Listagem de Manutenções",
    "render": 4
  },
  {
    "value": "supply",
    "label": "Listagem de Abastecimentos",
    "render": 5
  },
  {
    "value": "violation",
    "label": "Listagem de Infrações",
    "render": 6
  },
  {
    "value": "idle_itens",
    "label": "Listagem de Itens Ociosos",
    "render": 7
  },
  { "value": "history", "label": "Listagem de Histórico", "render": 8 }
]
```

The code(
as simplified as possible):

```
function Reports() {
  registerLocale("pt-BR", el);

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      render: 0
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      console.log(values);
    }
  });

function renderType(option) {
    formik.setFieldValue("render", option.render);
  }

return (
    <ContainerStyled>
      <ReportMainContainer>
        <ContainerFilters>
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <HeaderFilter>RELATÓRIOS</HeaderFilter>
            <BodyFilter>
              <FieldContainer>
                <LabelStyled>Tipo de Relatório</LabelStyled>
                <SelectStyled
                  options={reportTypeOptions}
                  placeholder="Selecione o tipo"
                  noOptionsMessage={() => "Nenhuma opção encontrada"}
                  onChange={renderType}
                />
              </FieldContainer>
              {formik.values.render === 1 ? (
                ""
              ) : formik.values.render === 2 ? (
                <TraveledKmsFilter />
              ) : formik.values.render === 3 ? (
                <OfflineItensFilter />
              ) : formik.values.render === 4 ? (
                <MaintenanceFilter />
              ) : formik.values.render === 5 ? (
                <SupplyFilter />
              ) : formik.values.render === 8 ? (
                <HistoryFilter />
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </BodyFilter>
            <ButtonsFilter>
              <FilterButton type="submit" color="#555">
                Visualizar
              </FilterButton>
            </ButtonsFilter>
          </form>
        </ContainerFilters>
      </ReportMainContainer>
      <TableContainer>
        {formik.values.render === 1 ? (
          <Vehiecles />
        ) : formik.values.render === 2 ? (
          <TraveledKms />
        ) : formik.values.render === 3 ? (
          <OfflineItens />
        ) : formik.values.render === 4 ? (
          <Maintenance />
        ) : formik.values.render === 5 ? (
          <Supply />
        ) : formik.values.render === 8 ? (
          <History />
        ) : (
          "asdsadasd"
        )}
      </TableContainer>
    </ContainerStyled>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the onChange in the button? <FilterButton type="submit" color="#555" onChange={renderType}>

Comment: yea, as i said in the description... doenst work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution that worked, for who encounter a similar issue:

Declare useState to do the work inside the onSubmit:

```
const [reportType, setReportType] = useState(0); //new

  registerLocale("pt-BR", el);

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      render: 0
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      setReportType(values.render); //new
    }
  });
```

Then, call "reportType" to be the condition to the ternary operator, instead of formik.values.render:

```
<TableContainer>
        {reportType === 1 ? (
          <Vehiecles />
        ) : reportType === 2 ? (
          <TraveledKms />
        ) : reportType === 3 ? (
          <OfflineItens />
        ) : reportType === 4 ? (
          <Maintenance />
        ) : reportType === 5 ? (
          <Supply />
        ) : reportType === 8 ? (
          <History />
        ) : (
          "asdsadasd"
        )}
</TableContainer>
```